# Use of comma as decimal separator

Tags: notation

It seems like an easy question. But I can't find an answer in the internet regarding this matter. 
What do you mean by "Average nozzle velocity = $50,6 m/s$"? Convert $50,6$ as one in $m/s$.

Comment: Does 50,6 mean $50 + \frac{6}{10}$?

Comment: I don't know too sir. But this is the link, http://www.t-iss.com/downloads/datasheets/linethrower.pdf

Comment: @vadim123 yes, it does, at least in Germany; I had a German student once. I was not aware that this usage also occurred in the Netherlands.

Comment: Note that one of the James Bond books written, after the death of Ian Fleming, by a different author, talks extensively about a line throwing tool, used on a ski slope to save someone

Comment: http://jamesbond.wikia.com/wiki/Schermuly_Pains-Wessex_Speedline

Answer (score 4):

$50,6$ does, in fact, mean $50+\frac{6}{10}$; that's just an alternate notation. Using a period to separate decimal places from the rest of the number seems to be common practice only in the US and the UK, from what I've seen and read. Commas seem to be preferred in place of decimal points in most other countries.

The reverse is also true, so what someone from the US or the UK might recognize as "$12,345.67$," someone from France, Germany, the Netherlands, or elsewhere might think of as "$12.345,67$," instead.